# PyFlink-NiFi Datastream Integration

Tags: python, apache-flink, apache-nifi, flink-streaming, pyflink

I need to process data coming from NiFi using PyFlink for a project, but the PyFlink documentation does not mention a NiFi connector, and we don't want to use Kafka in between. Is there an alternative way to achieve this?

I have successfully achieved data transfer using Kafka, but it introduces an additional process. To avoid this, I want to transfer data from NiFi to PyFlink directly over NiFi ports (output process).

Answer (score 0):

The Apache Flink NiFi connector has been removed as of Flink 1.16, see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-26687. You either need to use Flink 1.15 or an older version, or you can try to compile the NiFi connector for a newer version of Flink yourself.